# JSON-PHP/MySQL - Retrieving info from DB

Tags: php, json

I am using a JSON script ot print out a list of information (later it is sent to my iPhone application, all works fine on that end) with a specific value in a row in my table in my db.

I have managed to do this, however I am looking to expand my search results.

Working Code - obviously i setup

```
$link = mysql_connect ($host, $uid, $pwd) or die ("Could Not Connect");
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Could Not Connect to Database");
$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id, story, releasedate, title, youtube, picture FROM movies     WHERE category='Action'");
while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"users":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

I guess where line #4 is, at the end of that, I would like to to do the following, but cannot find any sample code for it.

Example Code:

......from Movies WHERE category CONTAINS 'Action'");

that obviously does not work and I get an error, pretty much my category row has multiple values for movies, ie DRAMA,Action Sustepnse etc in one row, as some movies are a mix of categories now a days, and would like it filtered out properly without the hassle of adding addition category rows in my db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

this will select movies that belong to one of these genres

```
WHERE category IN ('action', 'horror', 'comedy')
```

but if you want to search if the category contains action or drama or horror you need

```
WHERE category LIKE '%Action%' OR category LIKE '%Drama%'...
```

Comment: Note: This is like saying category is in action OR horror OR comedy

Comment: @Trevor, yeah true, but the question is not very clear so i had to assume that when he said CONTAINS...

Comment: some movies I have multiple values in  the category row, IE Horror, Drama, Action  in one movie, that one will not print, I assume since it has multiple values, how could I specify it printing out as well ?

Comment: using LIKE will do this for you.. also check this for more info mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: thank guys, great link and thanks for the coding!!! '%DRAMA%' value did it, thanks again, one step closer ot my movie app been completed.

Comment: @bharath I was just clarifying. :)